# SharePoint List Query JavaScript Variable Access Issue

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint

I am trying to figure out why I cannot access the variable `theHeaders` outside of the function. I have tried returning it and then calling the function directly and I get a `colListItem` on defined. I called it like so:

`alert(onQuerySucceeded());` and `alert(onQuerySucceeded(sender, args));`

I get an undefined everytime.

How can I access  `theHeaders` outside of the functions?

What I don't understand is why I can get it to work in an alert() message in the `onQuerySucceeded()` function but I cannot do something like `doucment.write`. I get a permissions denied error if I try any other action than alert()
JavaScript:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/dev/';
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
function retrieveListItems()
{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('myList');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Title' /></IsNotNull>  </Where>");
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,     this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) 
{


    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    var theHeaders = "";
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) 
    {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        theHeaders = theHeaders + oListItem.get_item('Title');


    }
    alert(theHeaders);


}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) 
{
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: It works for me. which browser are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer. You got the document.write to work or you accessed the variable "theHeaders" outside of the function?

Comment: yes. i placed document.write in place of alert and it worked. try placing html label and display theHeaders value in the label.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable at the top of your file (where you declare siteUrl) and you remove the declaration from within your function, you should be able to access it outside of the function. However, that would mean that you're changing the scope of your variable. If you're ok with that, it should work.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to write the result to the page rather than displaying an alert message. Whenever I switch the alert message out with doucment.write or something, I get a permissions error.

Comment: Does it work with console.log()? What is actually being printed on the alert/console?

Comment: The contents of the Title column are displayed in a string like so "OneTwoThreeFourFive" (Column values are One, Two, Three, Four, Five)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write` because it's going to destroy your page content. Inject your result into a `div` is better. Something like :

```
document.querySelector('#myDiv').innerHTML = theHeaders
```

By the way, you cannot use `alert(onQuerySucceeded());` because `onQuerySucceeded()` is called asynchronously from `retrieveListItems()`, so it cannot return a value.